# python sqlite string insertion

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to insert a string that was received as an argument into a sqlite db using python:

```
    def addUser(self, name):

            cursor=self.conn.cursor()
            t = (name)
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users ( unique_key, name, is_online, translate) VALUES (NULL, ?, 1, 0);", t)
            self.conn.commit()
```

I don's want to use string concatenation because http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html advises against it.

However, when I run the code, I get the exception

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users ( unique_key, name, is_online, translate) VALUES (NULL, ?, 1, 0);", t)
pysqlite2.dbapi2.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 7 supplied
```

Why is Python splitting the string by characters, and is there a way to prevent it from doing so?

EDIT:

changing to `t = (name,)`
gives the following exception

```
print "INSERT INTO users ( unique_key, name, is_online, translate) VALUES (NULL, ?, 1, 0)" + t
exceptions.TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need this:

```
t = (name,)
```

to make a single-element tuple.

Remember, it's **commas** that make a tuple, not brackets!

Comment: It now generates a new exception:
`print "INSERT INTO users ( unique_key, name, is_online, translate) VALUES (NULL, ?, 1, 0)" + t
exceptions.TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects`

Comment: @iliaden: It's your new `print` statement that's failing.  Your original statement `cursor.execute("INSERT ... (NULL, ?, 1, 0);", t)` will now work.  To make the `print` work, replace the `+` with a `,`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `t` variable isn't a tuple, i think it is a 7-length string. To make a tuple, don't forget to put a trailing coma:

```
t = (name,)
```

Comment: It now generates a new exception:
`print "INSERT INTO users ( unique_key, name, is_online, translate) VALUES (NULL, ?, 1, 0)" + t
exceptions.TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects`